# Access to shared_path in deploy.rb

Tags: capistrano3

I try to set command map using shared_path like that:

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = "php #{shared_path.join('composer.phar')}"
```

But the path is /var/www/xxx not using the path I set on :deploy_to deploy/staging.rb.

I guess this is because staging.rb is loaded after.

What the right way then?

Comment: In Capistrano 2, I solve this problem by using deferred variable with [set(name, &block)](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Configuration-Variables-Set#block) but I think this custom DSL was removed in Capistrano 3.

Anyone know what is the alternative ?

Comment: You can now use fetch. But Not sure it will work for command_map

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and although I don't think I have found the best way. I have found a way.

My default :deploy_to in deploy.rb points to '/var/www/my_app'. And I have a development stage where the server uses the same path. But my production server uses '/home/httpd/something/else' so I put :deploy_to in production.rb expecting it to deploy to that path. And everything works except the composer command. The composer.phar file is downloaded to the correct shared path and the files are deployed correctly. But when composer runs it tries to find it in '/var/www/my_app/shared'.

What I did was instead of putting the SSHKit.config.command_map by it self in deploy.rb, put it in a task. Something like:

```
namespace :deploy do

    before :starting, :map_composer_command do
        on roles(:app) do |server|
            SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = "#{shared_path.join("composer.phar")}"
        end
    end

    ...
end
```

It feels like SSHKit.config.command_map runs "to early" or something. This seems to help. It works for me at least. And I had the exact same issue.

Edit:
I got some help from an issue I posted on [capistrano/composer](https://github.com/capistrano/composer/issues/22).